# HTML5: Resizing a canvas

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, canvas

All this time I worked on an app in a 800x480 resolution (popular phone resolution).

My canvas HTML:

```
<canvas id="main" width="800" height="480">
```

Now to make it fullscreen for other resolutions, I do the following after a resize event:

```
$('#main').css('height', window.innerHeight);
$('#main').css('width', window.innerWidth);
```

This works but the problem is I can't maintain the aspect ratio this way.
800x480 is 4:3, but if I run this app on a 5:3 phone, some things (especially circles) will look stretched.

Is there any way to make it look good on all resolutions without having to create a unique set of images and code for every aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS properties `width` and `height` stretch the canvas, in order to scale the board, you must use `.attr` instead of `.css`, this will work, but, something to note:

If you want the canvas to look perfect on mobile phones, too, you must pay attention to `window.devicePixelRatio`.

### What's devicePixelRatio

MDN:

> The devicePixelRatio property returns the ratio between physical pixels and device independent pixels in the current display.

What does it mean? it means how many pixels does a device show, in one physical pixel.

If a device's pixel ratio is 2, it means two graphical pixels are drawn in a single physical pixel.

In order to make your canvas look perfect, you must do this trick:

set width and height of canvas to the amount you want multiplied by devicePixelRatio, i.e

```
$('canvas').attr({
  'width': window.innerWidth*devicePixelRatio,
  'height': window.innerHeight*devicePixelRatio
});
```

Then, scale your canvas down with CSS:

```
$('canvas').css({
  'width': window.innerWidth + 'px',
  'height': window.innerHeight + 'px'
});
```

It seems `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` are not right at first, I tried wrapping the code in a 100 milisecond setTimeout and it worked, I guess you can reduce the delay to something like 10 miliseconds, test it.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mdibaiee/7o4tLr4L/

To test on your mobile:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/mdibaiee/7o4tLr4L/show/

Comment: Thanks, but I still have some issues. I tried this on a 1280x720 phone so I put those width/height values in the canvas, except what happens is that the screen becomes smaller. I now have black bars on the right and bottom. If I enter 800x480 it will be fullscreen.

Comment: I meant you have to do those `window.innerWidth*devicePixelRatio` using DOM, not HTML, it won't work, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @P.Henderson Test it now

Comment: I have tried this, but for some reason it doesn't make it full screen. The canvasses are now about 60% of the window size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media for different resolutions like tablets and phones for example

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 640px) {
/* Styles */
}
```